# Vimeo video is not playing when i change embedded settings in privacy

Tags: android, vimeo-api

I am playing the video using Vimeo API and I am able to play the video successfully using "anywhere settings" under privacy. But when I changed the privacy settings to "Only on sites I choose " the video is not playing because of privacy error.

Error: Sorry
Because of its privacy settings, this video cannot be played here.

i have used the code below to play the video using webview:

```
webView1.loadData("<iframe src=\"http://player.vimeo.com/video/"+VIDEO_ID+"\" width=\"180px\" height=\"180px\" frameborder=\"0\" webkitallowfullscreen mozallowfullscreen allowfullscreen></iframe>", "text/html", "utf-8");
```

Answer (score 2):

This policy means that video cannot be played directly on devices. Only as embedded video on sites which you choose(For example iframe with this video). So it's not android/webview issue.